# I need a hint for sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve values from db and I am stack from start because sqlite3 is unable to open the db file after I was giving the right path.

Version 1:

```
sqlite_file = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', 'sqlite:///db.sqlite')
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()
```

Version 2:

```
sqlite_file = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()
```

Where:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', 'sqlite:///db.sqlite')
```

In both situations the error is

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/avb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 209, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/avb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 197, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/avb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/avb/app.py", line 222, in <module>
    conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Comment: For `sqlite3.connect()` start out using the actual filename (e.g. `example.db`) as the argument.  Same for `environ.get()` use the actual filename, not the `sqlite:///` address.

Comment: Great - just moved my comment as an answer, please mark accepted if it solves your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `sqlite3.connect()` start out using the actual filename (e.g. example.db) as the argument.
Same for `environ.get()`: use the actual filename, not the `sqlite:///` address.